# Image Uploading and Signup Code

Tags: php, html, image, web, upload

Here is my code for image upload and inserting data into a Database, but it is not working properly, and also not showing any errors.

```
<?php
if(isset($_Post['submitbtn']))
{
    $target_dir = "Resources/images/users/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    if (file_exists($target_file))
    {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }   
    if (file_exists($target_file)) 
    {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) 
    {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    if ($uploadOk == 0) 
    {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } 
    else 
    {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
        {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }

    $qur = "insert into users values ('"+$_Post['Id']+"','"+$_Post['firstname']+"','"+$_Post['lastname']+"','"+$_Post['email']+"','"+$_Post['Password']+"','"+'shopkeeper'+"','"+$target_file+"')";

    if(mysqli_query($con,$qur))
    {
        echo "Data Saved";
    }
    else
    {
         die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Debug more. Concat is not `+` but rather `.` in PHP. Plus you have sql injection vulnerabilities. And its `$_POST` not `$_Post` ... and ... and ... ugh. I'm out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are too many errors

Comment: @incredibleHat Thanks ;) Worked :P :D